# How to find the next instance of text in HTML using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a program that looks up the National Food Holiday for the current day using this site: https://foodimentary.com/today-in-national-food-holidays/may-holidays/.

So far I've been able to consistently get the tag with the current date, but I'm having trouble using that as a base reference to get the associated Food Day. Here's what I have so far:

```
month = date.today().strftime('%b') # Get month
day = date.today().strftime('%d') # Get day
date = f'{month.lower()}-{day}' # Format date 

# Get HTML from home page
url = 'https://foodimentary.com/today-in-national-food-holidays/todayinfoodhistorycalenderfoodnjanuary/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser') # Parse HTML with Beautiful Soup

# Get the current month URL
months = soup.find('ul', id='menu-months', class_='menu') # Isolate the months table
monthUrl = months.find('a', href=True, string=month)['href'] # Get the month URL for the current month

# Get HTML from month page, parse
r = requests.get(monthUrl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

# Find tag with URL that contains formatted date
holidayTag = soup.select_one(f'a[href*={date}]')
print(holidayTag)

# TODO: Get the name of the food day based on holidayTag
```

Using my browser's developer console, it seems like the most consistent pattern to correlate date with name of food holiday is that the holiday is always the next instance of text after the date tag. Here's an example piece of HTML:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
   <strong><a title="May&nbsp;29" href="https://foodimentaryguy.wordpress.com/2011/05/29/may-29/">May 29</a></strong><br>
   <span style="color:#000000;"><a style="color:#000000;" href="https://foodimentary.com/2017/02/12/february-12th-is-national-biscotti-day/">National Biscuit Day</a></span>
   <div style="text-align:center;"><strong><a title="May&nbsp;28" href="https://foodimentaryguy.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/may-28/">May 28</a></strong><br>
      <span style="color:#000000;"><a style="color:#000000;" href="https://foodimentary.com/2016/05/28/may-28-is-national-brisket-day/">National Brisket Day</a></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

My question is: how can I use Beautiful Soup to get the name of the holiday from the date tag?

Comment: From your sample html, what exactly is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This text is very unstructured (most probably written by hand and not machine generated). I recommend using `re` module for main parsing:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://foodimentary.com/today-in-national-food-holidays/may-holidays/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
txt = soup.select_one('section[role="main"]').text

out = {}
for day, names in re.findall(r'^([A-Z][^\n]+\d\s*)$(.*?)\n\n', txt, flags=re.DOTALL|re.M):
    out[day.strip()] = [name.replace('\xa0', ' ') for name in names.strip().split('\n')]

# pretty print on screen:
from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'May 1': ['National Chocolate Parfait Day'],
 'May 10': ['National Liver and Onions Day'],
 'May 11': ['National “Eat What You Want” Day'],
 'May 12': ['National Nutty Fudge Day'],
 'May 13': ['National Apple Pie Day',
            'National Fruit Cocktail Day',
            'National Hummus Day'],
 'May 14': ['National Brioche Day', 'National Buttermilk Biscuit Day'],
 'May 15': ['National Chocolate Chip Day'],
 'May 16': ['National Barbecue Day'],
 'May 17': ['National Cherry Cobbler Day'],
 'May 18': ['National Cheese Souffle Day', 'I love Reese’s Day'],
 'May 19': ['National Devil’s Food Cake Day'],
 'May 2': ['National Chocolate Truffle Day'],
 'May 20': ['National Quiche Lorraine Day', 'National Pick Strawberries Day'],
 'May 21': ['National Strawberries and Cream Day'],
 'May 22': ['National Vanilla Pudding Day'],
 'May 23': ['National Taffy Day'],
 'May 24': ['National Escargot Day'],
 'May 25': ['National Brown-Bag-It Day', 'National Wine Day'],
 'May 26': ['National Blueberry Cheesecake Day', 'National Cherry Dessert Day'],
 'May 27': ['National Italian Beef Day', 'National Grape Popsicle Day'],
 'May 28': ['National Brisket Day'],
 'May 29': ['National Biscuit Day'],
 'May 3': ['National Raspberry Popover Day',
           'National Raspberry Tart Day',
           'National Chocolate Custard Day'],
 'May 30': ['National Mint Julep Day'],
 'May 31': ['National Macaroon Day'],
 'May 4': ['National Candied Orange Peel Day',
           'National Homebrew Day',
           'National Hoagie Day'],
 'May 5': ['National Enchilada Day – Happy Cinco de Mayo!'],
 'May 6': ['National Crepe Suzette Day'],
 'May 7': ['National Roast Leg of Lamb Day'],
 'May 8': ['National Coconut Cream Pie Day'],
 'May 9': ['National Shrimp Day', 'National Foodies Day*']}
```